# How to set text for TextField in SwiftUI on button click

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to set text for `Textfield` in `SwiftUI` on button clicked. I tried using `@State` variable but its giving error

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: //TextFields States
    @State var textFieldText:String = ""



//TextField Code
TextField("Enter some text", text: $textFieldText)
                .padding(.all, 9.0)
                .frame(width: 350, height: 50.0)
                .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
                    print("=====Tapped======")
                })
                .border(Color.green, width: 4)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            



//On button Click 
self.$textFieldText = "Changed Text"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try Below code (tested in Xcode: 11.2.1)

```
struct ContentView: View {

   @State var name: String = ""
   var body: some View {

       VStack {
           TextField("Please enter", text: $name)
           Button(action: {
               self.name = "Hello text"
           }) {
               Text("Press")
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create the action of button-like bellow

```
@State var name: String = "My Name is jack"

   var body: some View {

       VStack {
           TextField("Name:", text: $name)
           Button(action: {
               self.name = "My Name is Tim"
           }) {
               Text("Change Name")
           }
       }
   }
```